# VirtualBox: guest OS not receiving IP number

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu Server LTS 18.04 headless host on which I installed VirtualBox 6.1.

I created a VM, using the following settings:

```
VBoxManage createvm --name Ubuntu-Server-18.04 --register
VBoxManage modifyvm Ubuntu-Server-18.04 --memory 2048 --acpi on --boot1 dvd --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 em1
VBoxManage createhd --filename /mnt/raiddisk/vm/Ubuntu-Server-18.04.vdi --size 10000
VBoxManage storagectl Ubuntu-Server-18.04 --name "IDE Controller" --add ide
VBoxManage storageattach Ubuntu-Server-18.04 --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium /mnt/raiddisk/vm/Ubuntu-Server-18.04.vdi
VBoxManage storageattach Ubuntu-Server-18.04 --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium /mnt/raiddisk/vm/installfiles/ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso
VBoxManage modifyvm Ubuntu-Server-18.04 --vrde on
```

I then start the vm:

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm Ubuntu-Server-18.04
```

But I when I try to see if the VM has an ip number I see this:

```
NIC 1: MAC: 0800284838AG, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'em1', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none

VRDE: enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 3389, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
```

How can I get the guest OS to receive an IP number?

I have also installed the Extension Pack.

I have a dhcp router on the network under 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to open up the required port on my server. VRDE was, in this case, listening on port 3389. After I added that port to my firewall rules, I was able to connect to the virtual machine using remote desktop.